# Show content of OpenSSL::X509::Store object

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, ocsp

A bit desperate on this one...

I am implementing an OCSP checking service, mainly based on those two examples:
http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/OpenSSL/OCSP.html
[How to programmatically check if a certificate has been revoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244084/how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-certificate-has-been-revoked/16257470#16257470)

I already verified the validity of my request via the openssl client:

```
openssl ocsp -issuer  ISSUER_OF_TESTCERT.pem.crt -cert TESTCERT.pem.crt -url http://url.of.ocspservice/ocsp -VAfile SIGNING_CERT_OF_OCSP_SERVICE_RESPoNSE.pem.crt
```

this gives me:

```
Response verify OK
TESTCERT.pem.crt good
This Update: <timestamp>
```

when using ruby's openssl api, i also get a positive response, 200 OK

However, once i want to verify the the response, i get

```
warning: error:27069076:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found
```

so here is how i try to verify the response:

```
# instantiate a ocsp response object from the http response body (side note: instantiating a BasicResponse object directly let's the irb segfault in the strangest way)
response = OpenSSL::OCSP::Response.new http_response.body
# transform into BasicResponse
basic_response = response.basic
# instantiate certificate store
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
# add the ocsp responder's cert and its root ca cert
cert_store.add_file('ocsp_cert')
cert_store.add_file('ocsp_cert_root')
# finally the verification
basic_response.verify([], cert_store)
# result:
=> OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found
```

when i try to double-add certs, i do get the expected error:

```
# instantiate certificate store
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
# double-add the ocsp responder's cert and its root ca cert
cert_store.add_file('ocsp_cert')
cert_store.add_file('ocsp_cert')
# result:
=> cert already in hash table (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
```

i'm not sure how else to trouble shoot, as i am not good in reading the source of these functions.
This leads me to my questions:
1. Is there any way to dump and analyse the content of said hash table, so i can be sure the right certificates are loaded?
2. Am i missing something obvious here?

thanks for any input and feedback.

fyi, the system i try to verify certificates against is the ocsp responder of the Estonian id card certificate centre.

Comment: I just verified that `basic_response.verify([], cert_store)` works as expected. Are you sure you've added the entire cert chain? For example, if you verify a response from the Symantec/Verisign OCSP responder for the certificate on `www.verisign.com` you need to add both `Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3` and `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`

Comment: I did indeed verify that the cert chain for the ocsp responder certs is complete, hence the two added certs ocsp_cert and its issuer, ocsp_cert_root.
Just to be very clear, i'm requesting the status a client cert which itself has one intermediary issuer and a top CA cert. the ocsp responder cert however only has two levels.

in the cert_store, i would only load the two ocsp certs, as these are the chain for the "signer certificate", right?

however, even loading all five of these certificates did not help. could this mean that the response must be signed with a different non-present cert?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my earlier comment, here's an example script that uses the current certificate on `www.verisign.com`.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

data = Net::HTTP.get(URI("http://sr.symcd.com/MFEwTzBNMEswSTAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBR0JBRnBp/14Jg/Xj4aa6BlKlQVdQQUAVmr5906C1mmZGPWzyAHV9WR52oCEB8AC4suGGDADBOTgwigBIE="))
response = OpenSSL::OCSP::Response.new(data)
issuer = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
root = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE0zCCA7ugAwIBAgIQGNrRniZ96LtKIVjNzGs7SjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
yjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQL
ExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJp
U2lnbiwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxW
ZXJpU2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0
aG9yaXR5IC0gRzUwHhcNMDYxMTA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMzYwNzE2MjM1OTU5WjCByjEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZW
ZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJpU2ln
biwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxWZXJp
U2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9y
aXR5IC0gRzUwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCvJAgIKXo1
nmAMqudLO07cfLw8RRy7K+D+KQL5VwijZIUVJ/XxrcgxiV0i6CqqpkKzj/i5Vbex
t0uz/o9+B1fs70PbZmIVYc9gDaTY3vjgw2IIPVQT60nKWVSFJuUrjxuf6/WhkcIz
SdhDY2pSS9KP6HBRTdGJaXvHcPaz3BJ023tdS1bTlr8Vd6Gw9KIl8q8ckmcY5fQG
BO+QueQA5N06tRn/Arr0PO7gi+s3i+z016zy9vA9r911kTMZHRxAy3QkGSGT2RT+
rCpSx4/VBEnkjWNHiDxpg8v+R70rfk/Fla4OndTRQ8Bnc+MUCH7lP59zuDMKz10/
NIeWiu5T6CUVAgMBAAGjgbIwga8wDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
BAMCAQYwbQYIKwYBBQUHAQwEYTBfoV2gWzBZMFcwVRYJaW1hZ2UvZ2lmMCEwHzAH
BgUrDgMCGgQUj+XTGoasjY5rw8+AatRIGCx7GS4wJRYjaHR0cDovL2xvZ28udmVy
aXNpZ24uY29tL3ZzbG9nby5naWYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFH/TZafC3ey78DAJ80M5+gKv
MzEzMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCTJEowX2LP2BqYLz3q3JktvXf2pXkiOOzE
p6B4Eq1iDkVwZMXnl2YtmAl+X6/WzChl8gGqCBpH3vn5fJJaCGkgDdk+bW48DW7Y
5gaRQBi5+MHt39tBquCWIMnNZBU4gcmU7qKEKQsTb47bDN0lAtukixlE0kF6BWlK
WE9gyn6CagsCqiUXObXbf+eEZSqVir2G3l6BFoMtEMze/aiCKm0oHw0LxOXnGiYZ
4fQRbxC1lfznQgUy286dUV4otp6F01vvpX1FQHKOtw5rDgb7MzVIcbidJ4vEZV8N
hnacRHr2lVz2XTIIM6RUthg/aFzyQkqFOFSDX9HoLPKsEdao7WNq
-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
store.add_cert(issuer)
store.add_cert(root)
puts response.basic.verify([], store)
```

The output should be "true".

Comment: It seems that the ocsp responder under http://demo.sk.ee/ocsp cannot handle requests similar to the one given in the example. it responds with a 404.

Comment: It's possible that OCSP responder doesn't respond to GET requests, but you have to generate your own OCSP request. That one is only valid for the verisign.com certificate.

Comment: yes, i generated my own request, and yes, it seems the GET request is not accepted on this server. i will have to verify that.