# erlang/elixir parse OCSPResponse (asn.1)

Tags: erlang, elixir, ocsp

Is there any way to parse OCSP response in erlang/elixir?
Probably I don't understand something, but it is ASN.1 type [OCSPResponse](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/1526eaead833b3bdcd3555a12e2af62c359e7868/lib/asn1/test/asn1_SUITE_data/rfcs/OCSP-2009.asn1) fails

```
 :public_key.der_decode(:OCSPResponse,data)
```

Also I have tried download and compile:

`asn1ct:compile("/Users/edenlab/workspace/ocsp_client/ocsp.asn1", [ber, verbose]).`

but it fails with a list of errors:

```
OCSP-2009:8: 'ATTRIBUTE' is not exported from PKIX-CommonTypes-2009
OCSP-2009:8: 'EXTENSION' is not exported from PKIX-CommonTypes-2009
...
OCSP-2009:180: illegal OBJECT IDENTIFIER
OCSP-2009:181: illegal OBJECT IDENTIFIER
{error,[{structured_error,{'OCSP-2009',8},
                          asn1ct_check,
                          {undefined_import,'ATTRIBUTE','PKIX-CommonTypes-2009'}},
```

Is there something like [OCSP lib in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244084/how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-certificate-has-been-revoked?lq=1)?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you post a sample value of `data` which should succeed?

Comment: undefined type
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,{asn1,{{undefined_type,'OCSPResponse'},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elixir code

```
with {:CertificateList, tbs_certs, _, _} <- 
:public_key.der_decode(:CertificateList, data),
{:TBSCertList, _, _, _, _, {:utcTime, ts}, certs, _} <- tbs_certs do
...
end
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation for future readers why does changing `:OCSPResponse` to `:CertificateList` solve the issue?

Comment: I don't know how it solve it, and why asn1 is not works still a question, but check one of examples from http://erlang.org/doc/man/public_key.html helps :\