# How to set timeout for cURL CRL checking?

Tags: powershell, curl, dns-over-https

```
 curl --connect-timeout 5 --doh-url $dohUrl --max-time 10 --tlsv1.3 ....
```

I've tried using either `--connect-timeout`, `--max-time` or both at the same time as you can see above, still cURL wastes so much time trying to check for CRL and I want to tell it to stop doing it if it takes longer than 5 seconds. currently, cURL keeps trying CRL for 20 seconds and then throws this error:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
```

this is an intentional scenario that I want cURL to navigate through. I do not want to set `--ssl-no-revoke` because that completely skips the CRL check, I just don't want cURL to keep trying CRL for more than 5 seconds and throw that error after 5 seconds instead of 20+ seconds.

> -m, --max-time 
> Maximum  time  in  seconds that you allow the whole operation to
> take.  This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from  hang‐
> ing  for  hours due to slow networks or links going down.  Since
> 7.32.0, this option accepts decimal values, but the actual time‐
> out will decrease in accuracy as the specified timeout increases
> in decimal precision.

quoting that from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout). why cURL not respecting that parameter? I set it to 10 seconds but it takes more than 20 seconds just stuck at CRL checking phase. is it the problem with where in the command I use that parameter?

I don't want to do anything extra and don't want to check the certificate or CRL myself with other methods.

you can easily test it, just set incorrect DoH details in Windows settings so that DNS resolution won't work but you will still be able to access web resources using their IP addresses.

Comment: [Apparently, you cannot just verify a site with a single simple request.](https://superuser.com/questions/742393/how-to-use-curl-to-verify-if-a-sites-certificate-has-been-revoked#:~:text=Apparently%2C%20you%20cannot%20just%20verify%20a%20site%20with%20a%20single%20simple%20request.)

Comment: Possible duplicate with: [How to programmatically check if a certificate has been revoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244084/how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-certificate-has-been-revoked?lq=1)

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear.