# Certificate Validation PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssl

I have researched SSL certificate validation with revocation checking using OpenSSL however this seems a rather complex method ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913440/openssl-how-to-check-if-a-certificate-is-revoked-or-not)).

1. Are there any simpler alternatives to OpenSSL when trying to validate SSL certificates with revocation checking in PHP?
2. Is there a more obvious way to do this in any other language which could then be called from the PHP script?

Comment: Certificate checking is only really reliable on PHP 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0, as streams (used by HTTPS) were insecure by default.

Comment: @Amelia I am using PHP 5.5.28: However PHP is not an absolute requirement (see question 2)