# how to do cryptography (digital signature)in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, cryptography, pkcs#7

I have done PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING in windows using wincrypt and I have to verify signature in linux. Can anyone tell by about good light crypto api on linux.

On  searching I found http://home.gna.org/cryptodev-linux/ and on compiling it i am getting this error crypto/hash.h: No such file or directory

Comment: [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/)? It's generally installed by default on most Linux distros. I can point a C++ wrapper I wrote ([sslpkix](https://github.com/jweyrich/sslpkix)) , but it's yet far from 1.0 - no docs, no sample code, etc. Anyway, maybe it sheds some light.

Comment: Well, normally OpenSSL is all you need. In what context do you need to verify a signature? Some code perhaps? On linux you might need to install some package that includes the kernel headers. For example on ubuntu - `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Comment: linux kernel does have crypto api. right? i want to use that if possible. It will be light then i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs because you don't have the kernel headers for your system/kernel, therefore when you try to compile, it's unable to find those headers.

More on your end goal, do you want to validate whether a certificate is signed by someone else's certificate?

If so, and if you're open to use [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/), take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288694/validating-x-509-certificate-on-linux/3343843#3343843).

Comment: yes.. certificate is signed by user in windows(using cryptoapi) and i have to validate it in linux machine...

Answer (score 3):

[NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/)

Comment: now that looks like a lot of headers! (if you know what i mean)

Comment: I want a light weight crypto api for verification on linux only

Answer (score 0):

I would either go with [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) (it also has its own API, just look on the side) or [Beecrypt](http://beecrypt.sourceforge.net/) which is probably a little easier to understand but not as complex in its functionality