# How do you verify a public key was issued by your private CA?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have created a CA cert, and used it to issue a public key. 
At a date in the future, I need to verify that the certificate loaded was issued by my CA.

How do I do that with the OpenSSL API (c++)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've reduced verify.c (in openssl/apps/) to the minimum functions required. Assumptions: cert and CA cert are both PEM format files. There are no CRLS or trusted list checks required.

Call verify() with the path to your cert and CA PEM files.

```
static int verify(const char* certfile, const char* CAfile);
static X509 *load_cert(const char *file);
static int check(X509_STORE *ctx, const char *file);

int verify(const char* certfile, const char* CAfile)
{
    int ret=0;
    X509_STORE *cert_ctx=NULL;
    X509_LOOKUP *lookup=NULL;

    cert_ctx=X509_STORE_new();
    if (cert_ctx == NULL) goto end;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    lookup=X509_STORE_add_lookup(cert_ctx,X509_LOOKUP_file());
    if (lookup == NULL)
        goto end;

    if(!X509_LOOKUP_load_file(lookup,CAfile,X509_FILETYPE_PEM))
        goto end;

    lookup=X509_STORE_add_lookup(cert_ctx,X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir());
    if (lookup == NULL)
        goto end;

    X509_LOOKUP_add_dir(lookup,NULL,X509_FILETYPE_DEFAULT);

    ret = check(cert_ctx, certfile);
end:
    if (cert_ctx != NULL) X509_STORE_free(cert_ctx);

    return ret;
}

static X509 *load_cert(const char *file)
{
    X509 *x=NULL;
    BIO *cert;

    if ((cert=BIO_new(BIO_s_file())) == NULL)
        goto end;

    if (BIO_read_filename(cert,file) <= 0)
        goto end;

    x=PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(cert,NULL, NULL, NULL);
end:
    if (cert != NULL) BIO_free(cert);
    return(x);
}

static int check(X509_STORE *ctx, const char *file)
{
    X509 *x=NULL;
    int i=0,ret=0;
    X509_STORE_CTX *csc;

    x = load_cert(file);
    if (x == NULL)
        goto end;

    csc = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    if (csc == NULL)
        goto end;
    X509_STORE_set_flags(ctx, 0);
    if(!X509_STORE_CTX_init(csc,ctx,x,0))
        goto end;
    i=X509_verify_cert(csc);
    X509_STORE_CTX_free(csc);

    ret=0;
end:
    ret = (i > 0);
    if (x != NULL)
        X509_free(x);

    return(ret);
}
```

Comment: can you explain the code with comments i am not able to understand the logic of this verification process

Comment: Is it possible to use memory instead of file? I would like to have A send certificate to B, and verify. Anyone like to share the code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: user180574 - I think you need to use BIO_new_mem_buf

Comment: You don't need the calls to `X509_STORE_add_lookup(... X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir());` and `X509_LOOKUP_add_dir(NULL, ...);` since you provide your CA file.

Comment: You can add flags to the context at `X509_STORE_set_flags(ctx, 0);`. `X509_V_FLAG_X509_STRICT | X509_V_FLAG_CHECK_SS_SIGNATURE | X509_V_FLAG_POLICY_CHECK` might be good choices. Be sure to stay away from `X509_V_FLAG_ALLOW_PROXY_CERTS`.

Comment: If the call to `X509_verify_cert(csc);` fails, I believe you can get the error code from `csc.error`. (The value from `ERR_get_error()` is worthless as it always appears to be `0`).

Comment: @John - Even with BIO_new_mem_buf I get a BIO, but X509_LOOKUP_load_file requires are file-path char*.. is there any other function to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

The `openssl verify -CAfile <CA_cert_filename> <unknown_cert_filename>` command will do what you want -- it's miserable to try to find the API that will do what you want, so I'd suggest finding the source code for the `openssl verify` routine.

(If you have choice of implementations, gnutls looks promising:

```
   #include <gnutls/x509.h>

   int gnutls_x509_crt_verify(gnutls_x509_crt_t cert, const  gnutls_x509_crt_t
   * CA_list, int CA_list_length, unsigned int flags, unsigned int * verify);
```

But OpenSSL *is* installed everywhere..)