# Programmatically verify certificate chain using OpenSSL API

Tags: c, openssl, x509, certificate-store, pkix

This is very similar to other questions but the ones I've looked at either don't have an answer or don't quite ask the same question.  I have a self-signed CA certificate, and two other certificates that are signed with that CA certificate.  I'm fairly sure the certificates are correct, because 'openssl verify' works:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server.pem
server.pem: OK
```

(The above is from memory, I don't have them in front of me, so it may be slightly off).

Now I want to verify the certificates programatically. I have a utility function with pseudocode below:

```
int verify_cert(X509 *cert, X509 *cacert)
{
     int ret;
     X509_STORE *store;
     X509_STORE_CTX *ctx;

     store = X509_STORE_new();
     X590_STORE_add_cert(store, cacert);

     ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
     X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, cert, NULL);

     ret = X509_verify_cert(ctx);

     /* check for errors and clean up */
}
```

My problem is that the above code always returns 'failed to find issuer certificate'.  What have I done wrong?  I believe I am creating a new store, adding the cacert, creating a new context, and adding the child cert to be verified to the context with a pointer to the store which contains the CA.  I'm pretty obviously doing something wrong, but I'm unsure what.

Any ideas?

**Update:** I'm aware I can save these certs to disk and use something like X509_LOOKUP_file or something similar. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't touch the disk unnecessarily.

Comment: I´m facing the same problem - did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @koch.trier no, unfortunately not. I've put it on the back burner for now and concentrating on other things.  I'm still looking for an answer here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [x509 certificate verification in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756553/x509-certificate-verification-in-c)

Comment: @noloader This is not a duplicate, the linked question doesn't use in-memory certs and an in-memory certificate store.  This does.

Comment: @clemej (Sorry if this is a year too late to help!) I'm using essentially identical code to you in our commercial application which uses a closed CA system. It works for us! Something that's caught us out is OpenSSL's checking of certificate extensions; perhaps `X509_STORE_CTX_set_purpose(X509_PURPOSE_ANY)` will help you if it's stuck because your CA cert doesn't have one of the usage extensions public CAs use? Apart from that I'm using literally *identical* code to yours and it works, so the difference must be in way I'm generating the certs compared to you.

Comment: Check this link: http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/trust-chain-building-for-X509-verify-cert-td26335.html It seems one needs to call "OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()".

Comment: another useful [code example](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x18361d55b3f7b4b00952efc35e22dd26781f2caac5e41111a3846e771e9cfb2b&fullName=pulp-master/playpen/certs/cert_validation.c&project=AndreaGiardini/pulp)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the normal validation routines (see [How do you verify a public key was issued by your private CA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412032/openssl-c-how-do-you-verify-a-public-key-was-issued-by-your-private-ca)), like the -verify function in OpenSSL does. You need to create a lookup method (X509_LOOKUP_METHOD) like X509_LOOKUP_file(), but which works with a character string instead of a filename. The code for X509_LOOKUP_buffer() is as follows.

Header file by_buffer.h:

```
/* File:   by_buffer.h */

#ifndef BY_BUFFER_H
#define    BY_BUFFER_H

#include <openssl/x509.h>

#ifdef    __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#define X509_L_BUF_LOAD    1
#define X509_LOOKUP_load_buf(x,name,type) \
        X509_LOOKUP_ctrl((x),X509_L_BUF_LOAD,(name),(long)(type),NULL)
X509_LOOKUP_METHOD *X509_LOOKUP_buffer(void);

#ifdef    __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif    /* BY_BUFFER_H */
```

The c program by_buffer.c:

```
/* by_buffer.c - copied and modified from crypto/x509/by_file.c */
/* Copyright (C) - should be the same as for OpenSSL
*/
#include "by_buffer.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "../crypto/cryptlib.h"
#include <openssl/lhash.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

static int by_buffer_ctrl(X509_LOOKUP *ctx, int cmd, const char *argc,
    long argl, char **ret);
X509_LOOKUP_METHOD x509_buffer_lookup=
    {
    "Load buffer into cache",
    NULL,        /* new */
    NULL,        /* free */
    NULL,         /* init */
    NULL,        /* shutdown */
    by_buffer_ctrl,    /* ctrl */
    NULL,        /* get_by_subject */
    NULL,        /* get_by_issuer_serial */
    NULL,        /* get_by_fingerprint */
    NULL,        /* get_by_alias */
    };

X509_LOOKUP_METHOD *X509_LOOKUP_buffer(void)
    {
    return(&x509_buffer_lookup);
    }

static int by_buffer_ctrl(X509_LOOKUP *ctx, int cmd, const char *argp, long argl,
         char **ret)
    {
    int ok=0;
    char *certBuf;

    switch (cmd)
        {
    case X509_L_BUF_LOAD:
        if (argl == X509_FILETYPE_DEFAULT)
            {
            X509err(X509_F_BY_FILE_CTRL,X509_R_LOADING_DEFAULTS);
            }
        else
            {
            if(argl == X509_FILETYPE_PEM)
                ok = (X509_load_cert_crl_buf(ctx,argp,
                    X509_FILETYPE_PEM) != 0);
            else
                ok = (X509_load_cert_buf(ctx,argp,(int)argl) != 0);
            }
        break;
        }
    return(ok);
    }

int X509_load_cert_buf(X509_LOOKUP *ctx, const char *certBuf, int type)
    {
    int ret=0;
    BIO *in=NULL;
    int i,count=0;
    X509 *x=NULL;

    if (certBuf == NULL) return(1);
        in=BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        if(in==NULL) goto err;

    if (type == X509_FILETYPE_PEM)
        {
        for (;;)
            {
            x=PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(in,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            if (x == NULL)
                {
                if ((ERR_GET_REASON(ERR_peek_last_error()) ==
                    PEM_R_NO_START_LINE) && (count > 0))
                    {
                    ERR_clear_error();
                    break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CERT_FILE,
                        ERR_R_PEM_LIB);
                    goto err;
                    }
                }
            i=X509_STORE_add_cert(ctx->store_ctx,x);
            if (!i) goto err;
            count++;
            X509_free(x);
            x=NULL;
            }
        ret=count;
        }
    else if (type == X509_FILETYPE_ASN1)
        {
        x=d2i_X509_bio(in,NULL);
        if (x == NULL)
            {
            X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CERT_FILE,ERR_R_ASN1_LIB);
            goto err;
            }
        i=X509_STORE_add_cert(ctx->store_ctx,x);
        if (!i) goto err;
        ret=i;
        }
    else
        {
        X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CERT_FILE,X509_R_BAD_X509_FILETYPE);
        goto err;
        }
err:
    if (x != NULL) X509_free(x);
    if (in != NULL) BIO_free(in);
    return(ret);
    }

int X509_load_crl_buf(X509_LOOKUP *ctx, const char *certBuf, int type)
    {
    int ret=0;
    BIO *in=NULL;
    int i,count=0;
    X509_CRL *x=NULL;

    if (certBuf == NULL) return(1);
    //in=BIO_new(BIO_s_file_internal());
        in=BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

        if(in==NULL) goto err;

    if (type == X509_FILETYPE_PEM)
        {
        for (;;)
            {
            x=PEM_read_bio_X509_CRL(in,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            if (x == NULL)
                {
                if ((ERR_GET_REASON(ERR_peek_last_error()) ==
                    PEM_R_NO_START_LINE) && (count > 0))
                    {
                    ERR_clear_error();
                    break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CRL_FILE,
                        ERR_R_PEM_LIB);
                    goto err;
                    }
                }
            i=X509_STORE_add_crl(ctx->store_ctx,x);
            if (!i) goto err;
            count++;
            X509_CRL_free(x);
            x=NULL;
            }
        ret=count;
        }
    else if (type == X509_FILETYPE_ASN1)
        {
        x=d2i_X509_CRL_bio(in,NULL);
        if (x == NULL)
            {
            X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CRL_FILE,ERR_R_ASN1_LIB);
            goto err;
            }
        i=X509_STORE_add_crl(ctx->store_ctx,x);
        if (!i) goto err;
        ret=i;
        }
    else
        {
        X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CRL_FILE,X509_R_BAD_X509_FILETYPE);
        goto err;
        }
err:
    if (x != NULL) X509_CRL_free(x);
    if (in != NULL) BIO_free(in);
    return(ret);
    }

int X509_load_cert_crl_buf(X509_LOOKUP *ctx, const char *certBuf, int type)
{
    STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *inf;
    X509_INFO *itmp;
    BIO *in;
    int i, count = 0;
    if(type != X509_FILETYPE_PEM)
        return X509_load_cert_buf(ctx, certBuf, type);
        in = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    if(!in) {
        X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CERT_CRL_FILE,ERR_R_SYS_LIB);
        return 0;
    }
        BIO_write(in, certBuf, strlen(certBuf));
    inf = PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio(in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(in);
    if(!inf) {
        X509err(X509_F_X509_LOAD_CERT_CRL_FILE,ERR_R_PEM_LIB);
        return 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < sk_X509_INFO_num(inf); i++) {
        itmp = sk_X509_INFO_value(inf, i);
        if(itmp->x509) {
            X509_STORE_add_cert(ctx->store_ctx, itmp->x509);
            count++;
        }
        if(itmp->crl) {
            X509_STORE_add_crl(ctx->store_ctx, itmp->crl);
            count++;
        }
    }
    sk_X509_INFO_pop_free(inf, X509_INFO_free);
    return count;
}
```

Routine in C++ which calls the above routines:

```
#include "by_buffer.h"
static int check(X509_STORE *ctx, const char *certBuf);
static X509 *load_cert(const char *certBuf);

int validateKey(const char *rsaKeyCA, const char *rsaCertificate) {
    int ret=0;
    X509_STORE *cert_ctx=NULL;
    X509_LOOKUP *lookup=NULL;

    cert_ctx=X509_STORE_new();
    if (cert_ctx == NULL) goto end;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    lookup=X509_STORE_add_lookup(cert_ctx,X509_LOOKUP_buffer());
    if (lookup == NULL)
        goto end;

    if(!X509_LOOKUP_load_buf(lookup,rsaKeyCA,X509_FILETYPE_PEM))
        goto end;

    lookup=X509_STORE_add_lookup(cert_ctx,X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir());
    if (lookup == NULL)
        goto end;

    X509_LOOKUP_add_dir(lookup,NULL,X509_FILETYPE_DEFAULT);

    ret = check(cert_ctx, rsaCertificate);
end:
    if (cert_ctx != NULL) X509_STORE_free(cert_ctx);

    return ret;
}

static X509 *load_cert(const char *certBuf)
{
    X509 *x=NULL;
    BIO *cert;

    if ((cert=BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())) == NULL)
        goto end;

    BIO_write(cert, certBuf, strlen(certBuf));

    x=PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(cert,NULL, NULL, NULL);
end:
    if (cert != NULL) BIO_free(cert);
    return(x);
}

static int check(X509_STORE *ctx, const char *certBuf)
{
    X509 *x=NULL;
    int i=0,ret=0;
    X509_STORE_CTX *csc;

    x = load_cert(certBuf);
    if (x == NULL)
        goto end;

    csc = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    if (csc == NULL)
        goto end;
    X509_STORE_set_flags(ctx, 0);
    if(!X509_STORE_CTX_init(csc,ctx,x,0))
        goto end;
    ////// See crypto/asn1/t_x509.c for ideas on how to access and print the values
    //printf("X.509 name: %s\n", x->name);
    i=X509_verify_cert(csc);
    X509_STORE_CTX_free(csc);

    ret=0;
end:
    ret = (i > 0);
    if (x != NULL)
        X509_free(x);

    return(ret);
}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of work to define a whole new callback mechanism. But it also seems to be the only way. Bonus points for the extensive example code.

Comment: This code is "correct" but all of it is completely useless! The central call in this code is `X509_STORE_add_cert`, which is exactly the same API call that the OP was originally using.  It's been wrapped up though in piles of obfuscating gloop by hiding it away inside the `X509_load_cert_buf` function then calling that in a very indirect way using `X509_LOOKUP_load_buf`. This code offers no advantage at all over the OP's original code which simply called `X509_STORE_add_cert` directly.

Comment: Sorry that I provided "useless" code! What I wanted to do was duplicate the openssl verify function, which works, as does MY code. I made no attempt to optimize it any better than OpenSSL's code.

Comment: It's not useless at all. Yes it seems convoluted in regard to the OP's basic requirement, but actually it would complement openssl's store/lookup functionality. See new [feature request](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/13134).

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem myself and started off with code very close to the OP. My certificate chain included 3 certificates:
Certificate 1 (root-ca) Issuer: root-ca Subject: root-ca
Certificate 2 (signing-ca) Issuer: root-ca Subject: signing-ca
Certificate 3 (device) Issuer: signing-ca Subject: device

I wanted to verify the device certificate. My ca.pem equivalent (wrt OP) contained the root-ca and signing-ca.

The X509_verify_cert function needs the entire certificate chain all the way to the root (root-ca & signing-ca) in the X509_store.

Below is my code that works for me. Checks on return values were omitted to lean the code down.

```
int getIssuerCert(X509_STORE *x509_store){
    STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *inf;
    X509_INFO *itmp;
    BIO *in;
    int i, count = 0;

    in = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_write(in, issuerCertStr, strlen(issuerCertStr)); //string containing root-ca & signing-ca
    inf = PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio(in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(in != NULL) BIO_free(in);
    for(i = 0; i < sk_X509_INFO_num(inf); i++) {
        itmp = sk_X509_INFO_value(inf, i);
        if(itmp->x509) {
            X509_STORE_add_cert(x509_store, itmp->x509);
            count++;
        }
        if(itmp->crl) {
            X509_STORE_add_crl(x509_store, itmp->crl);
            count++;
        }
    }
    sk_X509_INFO_pop_free(inf, X509_INFO_free);
    return 0;
}


int verify_cert(){
    int ret = 0;
    X509 *devCert = NULL;
    X509_STORE *x509_store = NULL;
    X509_STORE_CTX *x509_store_ctx = NULL;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    devCert = getDeviceCert(); //  Returns X509 pointer

    x509_store = X509_STORE_new();
    X509_STORE_set_verify_cb(x509_store, verify_cb);
    X509_STORE_set_flags(x509_store, 0);

    x509_store_ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();

    X509_STORE_CTX_init(x509_store_ctx, x509_store, devCert, NULL)

    X509_STORE_CTX_set_purpose(x509_store_ctx, X509_PURPOSE_ANY);
    ret = X509_verify_cert(x509_store_ctx);

    if(x509_store_ctx != NULL) X509_STORE_CTX_free(x509_store_ctx);
    if(x509_store != NULL) X509_STORE_free(x509_store);
    if(devCert != NULL) X509_free(devCert);
    EVP_cleanup();
    return ret;
}
```

I didn't need to create any lookup methods. The key for me was looping through my certificates from my string in memory so I had all the certificates I need to complete the chain. The string is equivalent to what I would have fed into openssl verify for the option -CAfile.

Also, make sure your X509 pointers are not null when the are used.

Answer (score 4):

I think, you can use "X509_STORE_set_verify_cb" to add a callback to identify the actual error:

```
static int  verify_cb(int ok, X509_STORE_CTX *ctx)
{
    if (!ok)
    {
        /* check the error code and current cert*/
        X509 *currentCert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx);
        int certError = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(ctx);
        int depth = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth(ctx);
        printCert(currentCert);
        printf("Error depth %d, certError %d", depth, certError)
    }

    return(ok);
}

int verify_cert(X509 *cert, X509 *cacert)
{
     int ret;
     X509_STORE *store;
     X509_STORE_CTX *ctx;

     store = X509_STORE_new();
     X509_STORE_set_verify_cb(store, verify_cb);
     X590_STORE_add_cert(store, cacert);

     ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
     X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, cert, NULL);

     ret = X590_verify_cert(ctx);

     /* check for errors and clean up */
}
```

Unless we know the error code it is difficult to guess the actual problem. The code otherwise looks OK.

Answer (score 3):

A **possible** answer (don't have the rep points to add a comment, sorry): the manpage for `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(3)` says,

```
When building its own certificate chain, an OpenSSL client/server will try to fill in
missing certificates from CAfile/CApath, if the certificate chain was not explicitly
specified (see SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert(3), SSL_CTX_use_certificate(3).
```

*(Failure to match parens theirs, not mine.)*

Which seems to mean that, as an alternative to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(3)`, it should be possible to use `SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert(3)` or `SSL_CTX_use_certificate(3)` -- both of which take a `X509 *` arg.  Thus obviating the need for Mr Ed's solution as seen above.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations ()` function: http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html

> SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() specifies the locations for ctx, at
>   which CA certificates for verification purposes are located. The
>   certificates available via CAfile and CApath are trusted.

You can generate a CA certificate file containing both ca.pem server.pem:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 rm CAfile.pem
 for i in ca.pem server.pem ; do
   openssl x509 -in $i -text >> CAfile.pem
 done
```

And then set `CAfile` variable to point to `CAfile.pem` file.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I'm confused, why would I need to specify a location (file or dir) when I'm loading the certificates explicitly using add_cert?

Comment: I have't found any X590_STORE_add_cert () function in OpenSSL, where does it come from? Usually you want to use SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations () function with a path to PEM file to verify certificate chain.

Comment: http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/x509_store.html . But here's the rub. These files aren't on disk. They're already in memory in x509 structs. I shouldn't really need to write them out to disk just to verify them .. Do I?

Comment: hey, what is SSleay ? OpenSSL says it's "the ancestor package of OpenSSL", why do you use it ? It really depends on how do you get these certificates, if they are located on disc, then use the function I posted above, let it do the work. if you want to verify a server certificate, then this is a different issue.

Comment: I'm not using ssleay but the functions are the same and that's the top hit on Google. Thanks for taking the time to answer but I'd really prefer a solution that doesn't involve touching the disk.

Answer (score 0):

See the official source code:
apps/verify.c

```c
static int check(X509_STORE *ctx, const char *file,
                 STACK_OF(X509) *uchain, STACK_OF(X509) *tchain,
                 STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crls, int show_chain);
```

You can see how to output 'OK' here:

```c
    if (i > 0 && X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(csc) == X509_V_OK) {
        printf("%s: OK\n", (file == NULL) ? "stdin" : file);
```

The function dependence can be found in apps/apps.c

Answer (score 0):

To properly verify a certificate chain, you can't just verify the "top" of the chain, because it could be an intermediate certificate that is the one stored on your machine.

For example, Let's Encrypt signs certs using their "R3" certificate, and this cert is in turn signed by "ISRG Root X1", but my Linux system has "R3" and not "ISRG Root X1" installed. So the verification chain stops in the middle, even though the certificate is valid:

```
DEBUG - chain[2]: FAILED: "ISRG Root X1"
DEBUG - chain[1]: VERIFIED: "R3"
DEBUG - chain[0]: VERIFIED: "www.myexample.com"
```

So the requirement is that there is a contiguous chain from the bottom (server's certificate) to some intermediate certificate that is in your trust store.

[Here](https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugins/compare/master...archiecobbs:monitoring-plugins:check_http-verify-host#diff-195b0f6b084f7955a84f1986a3d1193e3f19580dd0080694e26deb8d9cd57fdeR169) is an example of what I came up with for doing this loop.