# Error 0x0B07F069 and "no cert set for us to verify" during certifcate verification

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, x509, tls1.2

I've followed the advice on many other questions regarding this, and put something together, but my code doesn't work. It fails at `X509_verify_cert()` and `ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL)` results in:

```
error:0B07F069:x509 certificate routines:X509_verify_cert:no cert set for us to verify
```

Here's my code:

```
int tallis_ssl_verify(tallis_t *tallis, X509 *cert, X509 *CA)
{
    int rv;

    X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags(
            tallis->param,
            X509_CHECK_FLAG_NO_PARTIAL_WILDCARDS);

    X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host(tallis->param, tallis->host, 0);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(tallis->ssl_context, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
    SSL_set_verify(tallis->ssl_connection, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);

    ERR_clear_error();
    rv = SSL_get_verify_result(tallis->ssl_connection);

    if (rv != X509_V_OK)
        return 1;

    ERR_clear_error();
    X509_STORE_CTX *ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
    X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, cert, NULL);
    X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK);
    X509_LOOKUP *lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(store, X509_LOOKUP_file());

    X509_STORE_load_locations(
            store,
            "/etc/ssl/certs/UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem",
            NULL);

    X509_STORE_set_default_paths(store);

    X509_LOOKUP_load_file(
            lookup,
            "/etc/ssl/certs/UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem",
            X509_FILETYPE_PEM);

    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, cert);

    if (!store)
    {
        X509_STORE_free(store);
        return 1;
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(tallis->ssl_context);

    ERR_clear_error();
    rv = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(
            tallis->ssl_context,
            "/etc/ssl/certs/UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem",
            "/etc/ssl/certs");

    if (!rv)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        return 1;
    }

    ERR_clear_error();
    rv = X509_verify_cert(ctx);

    if (rv != 1)
    {
        fprintf(
                stderr,
                "%s\n%s\n",
                ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL),
                X509_verify_cert_error_string(ctx->error));

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try checking for errors on earlier calls like `X509_STORE_add_cert()`. One of those is probably failing which is why it claims there is nothing to verify.

Comment: Also see [Programmatically verify certificate chain using OpenSSL API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16291809), [x509 certificate verification in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2756553), etc.