# Verification Of x509 Certificates

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl, x509certificate, digital-signature

I have gone through many articles and questions @ SO about this but still I am not clear.
I have a digitally signed PE, I am able to calculate the Sha1 Hash of the file but do not know how to decrypt the signature using public key. I have read that it can be done using **openssl** source codes but they are just too much to go through. Can anyone provide me the respective source codes or links and details on how to use them? Is there any good tutorials available for the same?
TIA

Comment: Which particular acronym should we use for "PE"?

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756553/x509-certificate-verification-in-c

Comment: If you choose MS Windows as a platform, why don't you use Microsoft CryptoAPI? It's very simple to verify signature with certificate using them.

Comment: @owlstead- PE:: Portable Executable... :-)

Comment: We need to know the signature was generated. I presume PKCS#1 v1.5 using SHA-1 then? Does the PE use a container format for the signature?

Comment: @owlstead- Sorry, its PKCS#7 v3 and SHA1withRSAEncryption. Rest of the details are documented here:: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/Authenticode_PE.mspx

Comment: If you just use [`PKCS7_verify`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html) then OpenSSL will do the verification of the signature for you. It doesn't seem to be an overly difficult method call to use...

Answer (score 0):

you could use the openssl command line interface.
This should be something like:

openssl rsautl -verify -inkey 1-cert.pem -keyform PEM -certin -in signature > verified

If you want to use the library you could use the openssl cli especially the verify command as a start point.

Comment: I have to use the source code as I am trying to make an exe to do the same.